# Flask, is it possible to return itself URL after retrieve arguments

Tags: python, flask

For example:

I have a route: /foo

```
 @app.route('/foo')
 def foo():
     
     #the logic
```

Is it possible to retrieve arguments from url  /foo?arg1=abc&arg2=123

That's arg1=abc, arg2=123
Then redirect/keep the user within same URL but without arguments shown in the browser?

```
@app.route('/foo')
def foo():        
     arg1= request.args.get('arg1')
     arg2= request.args.get('arg2')

     if arg1 or arg2:
        #some logic

     #the logic
```

In other words, a user from URL (could be the link shared by someone else)

```
 /foo?arg1=abc&arg2=123
```

will be redirected to URL

```
/foo
```

However, I need the arguments (arg1,arg2) to make some business logic and render it to the template. Is it possible to achieve?

Appreciate your help!

Comment: You could redirect it with the name of the function itself  with `redirect(url_for(func_name))`. If it's in a blueprint, you could do with `redirect(url_for(blueprint_name.func_name))`.

Comment: finally, I use the session to store arguments. If value in session is not None, then save arguments to session, if have arguments, then do the logic.